# Re-running SQLAlchemy queries when connections get stale

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, connection-pooling, pyramid

I have SQLAlchemy connecting to Postgres via PGPool. PGPool is configured to recycle connections that are about 60s old.

I have two problems:

1) Sometimes, we get a huge query that takes more than 60s (I know it's bad... we're working on improving this) and subsequent queries fail because they rely on the same old connection that is no longer valid.

2) Similarly, when I start my Pyramid app using iPython, the connections get stale here when I stop to think for a moment.

When attempting to perform a query with a session with a stale connection, I get an exception saying:

```
OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection terminated due to client idle limit reached
ERROR:  connection terminated due to client idle limit reached
```

SQLAlchemy's pessimistic disconnect handling docs recommend testing the connection when you get it out of the pool. However, the connection is becoming stale *after* being checked out, so this wouldn't help much.

I think the right solution would be to refresh the session's connection upon getting this type of error:

```
session = MySession() # using scoped_session here
query = session.query(...)
try:
    rows = [r for r in query]
except OperationalError:
    # somehow tell query.session to use a new connection here and try again?
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

For me, executing

```
session.close_all()
```

makes the session then able run queries, at least until it idles out again.

Interestingly, running `session.remove()` or `session.close()`, like the [SQLAlchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/contextual.html) seems to imply should work, doesn't work; that makes future queries give `InvalidRequestError: Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back` (which of course `session.rollback()` doesn't fix) until calling `session.close_all()` .

I hope somebody can provide insight into *why* `session.close_all()` does the trick, and it may not be an appropriate solution for production, but that should at least make it so you don't have to restart the whole app in your iPython session.